# How to cast Int to Char in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, casting

With Java primitives it was easy to cast char code to symbol

```
int i = 65;
char c = (char) i; // 'A'
```

How to do the same with Kotlin?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Use the [`int.toChar()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-int/to-char.html) function to do it.

Comment: But it truncates int to 16 bits, so `128104.toChar()` doesn't give the desired result ()

Comment: @fdermishin then use a Long, instead of an Int

Comment: @david.barkhuizen That's not going to work. `Returns the Char with the numeric value equal to this number, truncated to 16 bits if appropriate.` https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-long/to-char.html

Comment: @fdermishin Agreed.  Please see my full answer for a correct solution.

Answer (score 1):

First convert the Int to ByteArray (with the correct byte order) using a ByteBuffer, then use the appropriate String constructor.

```
import java.nio.ByteBuffer
import java.nio.ByteOrder
import java.nio.charset.Charset

fun intToByteArray(n: Int, byteOrder: ByteOrder) =
    ByteBuffer.allocate(4).order(byteOrder).putInt(n).array()

fun byteArrayToUnicode(ba: ByteArray, charSet: Charset) =
    String(ba, charSet)

fun intToUniCode(n: Int, byteOrder: ByteOrder, charSet: Charset) =
    byteArrayToUnicode(intToByteArray(n, byteOrder), charSet)

fun test() {
    val charSet = Charset.forName("UTF-32BE")
    val n = 0x000000f7 // division sign (U+00F7)
    val s = intToUniCode(n, ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN, charSet)
    println(s)
}
```

Comment: Technically, this solution is for Java using Kotlin, won't work in native Kotlin.

Comment: Agreed. Intended for Kotlin running JVM on Android, and confirmed to work there.